# What is the best way to fill each row of a column based on a condition of another cell, within the same row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to fill a dataframe column 'Classification' with strings which indicate whether the value falls within the 200 lowest, or 200 highest values of a column titled, 'Valence_mean'.

So, if a value of a cell within the 'Valence_mean' column is in the 200 lowest values of the column's values, the label in the cell of the  'Classification' column of the same row, should be "Low_Valence". Otherwise, if a value of a cell within the 'Valence_mean' column is in the 200 highest values of the 'Classification' column's corresponding cell should be "high_valence".

df.head()

```
Out[31]: 
  Unnamed: 0      Theme Category   Source  Valence_mean  Valence_SD  \
0         I1   Acorns 1   Object  Pixabay      4.686275    0.954203   
1         I2   Acorns 2   Object  Pixabay      4.519608    0.841150   
2         I3   Acorns 3   Object  Pixabay      4.754902    0.958921   
3         I4  Alcohol 1   Object  Pixabay      4.685185    1.189111   
4         I5  Alcohol 2   Object  Pixabay      4.250000    1.136686   

   Valence_N  Arousal_mean  Arousal_SD  Arousal_N  
0        102      2.346535    1.602720        101  
1        102      2.227723    1.399151        101  
2        102      2.306931    1.514877        101  
3        108      2.865385    1.695555        104  
4        108      3.000000    1.700942        104  

df['Classification'] = ''
```

I am attempting to first code each cell of the column 'Classification', as 'Low_Valence', if it is in the list of 200 smallest 'Valence_mean' rows.

```
df.loc[df.Valence_mean in df.nsmallest(200, 'Valence_mean'), ['Classification']] = 'Low_Valence'
```

I also tried:

```
if df.Valence_mean.isin(df.nsmallest(200, 'Valence_mean')):
    df['Classification'] = 'Low_Valence'
if df.Valence_mean.isin(df.largest(200, 'Valence_mean')):
    df['Classification'] = 'Low_Valence'
```

The above codes generates an error. Wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this.

This solution works, but I am wondering if there is something more elegant:

```
small_Valence_df = df.nsmallest(200, 'Valence_mean')
high_Valence_df = df.nlargest(200, 'Valence_mean')
small_Valence_df['Classification'] = 'Low_Valence'
high_Valence_df['Classification'] = 'High_Valence'
frames = [small_Valence_df, high_Valence_df]
valence_df = pd.concat(frames)
valence_df.head()
```

Comment: I don't understand the explanation, may you rephrase it? And I don't see the column "classification" in the shown table

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto edited accordingly to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df.nsmallest(200,'Valence_mean').index.values,["Classification"]]="Low_valence"
```

You can get index values and change the values